# Do default constructors for private inner classes have a formal parameter?

Tags: java, language-design

Caveat #1: This is actually a potential two-parter: First, does the constructor for a private inner class have a formal parameter? If yes, why does the JLS say it doesn't? And if no, how/why not?

Caveat #2: **This question is not for speculation.** I'm looking for *authoritative* answers only.

Default constructors are defined in [JLS 8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9), which states (in part):

> The default constructor has no formal parameters, except in a **non-private** inner member class, where the default constructor implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class (§8.8.1, §15.9.2, §15.9.3).

*(emphasis added)*

The "non-private" bit seems odd to me: in order for an inner class to access fields defined in its enclosing class, it needs a reference to that instance. This should be the same regardless of whether the inner class is private.

In fact, javac seems to agree with me, in contradiction to the spec. If I compile this:

```
public class Ctors {
  private class MyInner {
  }
}
```

...and run `javap -c -private`, then we see a constructor with a single formal parameter, for the instance of the enclosing class:

```
$ javap -c -private Ctors\$MyInner
Compiled from "Ctors.java"
class Ctors$MyInner {
  final Ctors this$0;

  private Ctors$MyInner(Ctors);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #1        // Field this$0:LCtors;
       5: aload_0
       6: invokespecial #2        // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       9: return
}
```

For reference, this is on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_05.

So the JLS says that the default constructor for private inner member classes has no formal parameters, but javac/javap say it has one. (My understanding of the most natural way for things to work would also say it should have one, for the little that's worth.) Which is right, and why does the JLS specifically exclude private inner classes?

Comment: Which are you going to believe, your own eyes or the officially blessed spec?

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure of that. Firstly, the phrase is repeated a few times (e.g. in 8.8.1, which explains the "except..." phrase but also doesn't address private inner classes [as opposed to local/anonymous classes, which it does address]). And secondly, an inner class is by definition non-static; otherwise it's a nested class.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I'm no longer sure it makes sense---but I suspect it has to do with "receiver parameters", something that got added to Java 8 (see §8.4.1).  It has to do with putting `this` explicitly in the formal list so that you can put an annotation on it.  The clause you're asking about was not in JLS 7.

Comment: I'm remembering that, back when they first introduced these (poorly designed) features, there were several changes in the implementation as they tried to get the accessibility right while maintaining the appropriate illusions and not totally destroying object security.  I would hope that the docs finally caught up with the code, but I wouldn't want to bet on it.  But @ajb may be on to something in that the parm went from hidden (and hence not mentioned/acknowledged in the *language* spec) actually visible at the source language level.

Comment: I tried to see if there's a difference when I use reflection.  For a public inner class, `getConstructors` returns the default constructor, and `getParameterAnnotations` on that constructor returns an array of length 1, which I think reflects the implicit parameter for the enclosing instance.  But for a private inner class, I couldn't get `getConstructors` to return the default constructor at all.  Unless I did it wrong.

Comment: @ajb I need to get back to my day job :) but `getConstructors` only returns the public constructors, and the default constructor has the same visibility as its class (that's another one of the bullets in 8.8.9). `getDeclaredConstructors` should do the trick...

Comment: @yshavit Ah, you're right--the javadoc for `getDeclaredConstructors` says the default constructor is included in the list.  Seems strange since the default constructor isn't really "declared", I would have thought...

Comment: @yshavit Hmmmmm...  I tried `getDeclaredConstructors` and then `getParameterCount()` for each constructor.  The javadoc says `getParameterCount()` includes implicit parameters ("explicitly declared or implicitly declared or neither"--wonder what "neither" means?).  It output 1 both for a public inner class and a private inner class.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for looking into that! It's looking more and more like this is just an error in the JLS. And here I was hoping for some clever subtlety. :(

Comment: @yshavit Either in the JLS or the JRE...  What's really strange is that the JLS talks about an implicit parameter, but `isImplicit()` and `isSynthetic()` on the parameter both return false--in both the public and private class case.

Comment: @yshavit I'm pulling back on my previous comment: I'm no longer sure it is a typo. too many places metion it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.3, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1

Comment: is this related: `The fact that a non-private inner member class may be accessed by a different compiler than compiled it, whereas a local or anonymous class is always accessed by the same compiler that compiled it, explains why the binary name of a non-private inner member class is defined to be predictable but the binary name of a local or anonymous class is not (§13.1).`

Comment: "why does the JLS say it doesn't? "   Are you looking for a more authoritative answer than the Java Language Specification?  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @PeterLawrey If I'm really lucky, one of the people who wrote that part of the spec. :) Or a link to a discussion they had about it, etc. The spec here doesn't seem to make sense, and Oracle's own implementation seems to ignore it, so I'm looking of way of resolving that seeming confusion.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I read that. The weird thing though is that a private inner class is in _neither_ of those categories! It's (obviously) not a non-private inner member class, but it's also not a local or anonymous class. The standardization that applies to non-private inner classes would also seem to apply to "standard" private inner classes (not local/anon).

Comment: @yshavit BTW The JVM doesn't support private or protected classes.  Marking the class private or protected changes the modifier for the default constructor.  Also the JVM doesn't support calling a private constructor from another class.  Thus a synthetic constructor is added to the "private class" so it can be constructed from another class.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hm, that's interesting as a JVM internals issue. But fwiw, the language spec _does_ support private classes, as does the bytecode and reflection API: https://gist.github.com/yshavit/0aabc78418dbe2fc7c6e

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between the implementation and the specification.

In my opinion the "except" JLS statement

> ...**except** in a non-private inner member class...

is poorly worded.

It means, the compiler **is not required** to implicitly declares one formal parameter representing the immediately enclosing instance of the class... but **it could**.

---

Why implicitly formal parameter **is required** in non-private inner member class ?

From [JLS 8.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1):

> The member class may have been emitted by a compiler which is different than the compiler of the class instance creation expression. Therefore, there must be a standard way for the compiler of the creation expression to pass a reference (representing the immediately enclosing instance) to the member class's constructor

For example if i compile this inner class with a first compiler:

```
package p1;
public class Ctors {
    public class MyInner {
    }
}
```

if i want to compile this sub class with another compiler:

```
package p2;

import p1.Ctors;

public class SubCtors {
    public SubCtors() {
        new Ctors();
    }
}
```

the second compiler must be able to use the default constructor with the formal parameter. 
In this case the instance of the enclosing class with a `SubCtors` instance.

---

Why implicitly formal parameter **is not required** in non-private inner member class ?

Because a non-private inner member class is always accessed by the same compiler that compiled it. As you shown, javac generates the same constructor regardless to the class visibility but it is not require to. Another compiler implementation is free to choose another way.

There is also another point in [JLS 8.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.1) which is very much along the same line

> In a class instance creation expression for a **local class (not in a static context)** or anonymous class, §15.9.2 specifies the immediately enclosing instance of the local/anonymous class. The local/anonymous class is necessarily emitted by the same compiler as the class instance creation expression. That compiler can represent the immediately enclosing instance how ever it wishes. **There is no need for the Java programming language to implicitly declare a parameter in the local/anonymous class's constructor.**

Comment: I find it very charitable to call the usage of "except" ambiguous, as "A except B" has a very clear meaning: if B is false, A must be true. If they meant to leave in unspecified, they should have expressed themselves differently ...

Comment: Well, i was not sure that "except" was so restrictive.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's very ambiguous. If I say "everyone gets a new car except for Bob and Mary, who get each get a new bike" then I unambiguously establish (a) that everyone who isn't Bob or Mary gets a new car and (b) that Bob and Mary each get a new bike. But that aside, the section of 8.8.1, and particularly bullets 2-3 in it, talk about local and anonymous classes. There's nothing saying why a private inner class (that isn't local or anonymous) is closer to local/anon classes than it is to non-private classes.

Comment: @yshavit you are right. My english is not perfect. I have updated and completed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but my second point still applies. The last chunk you quoted in 8.8.1 explicitly says "for a local class... or anonymous class," but the example I used in my question was neither of these. Basically, the JLS talks in detail about non-private member classes, and about local/anonymous classes -- but says virtually nothing explicit about private, non-local, non-anonymous classes. Your answer seems to imply that these are closer to local/anonymous classes than to declared, non-private classes... but I don't see why that would be, intuitively or by the spec.

Comment: For me a "local class (not in a static context)" include private member class

Comment: Hm, maybe the point here is that if any external compiler needs to consume the class files, then it needs to know exactly how to instantiate the class, which is why that constructor's semantics are formally defined (bullet point 1 in 8.8.1). Otherwise, the JLS doesn't care. In _that_ sense, private member classes are closer to local/anon classes; their private-ness inherently means that no external compiler can use them, and so there doesn't need to be a standard semantic.