# Could not find matching constructor in integrated class

Tags: java, groovy

I define a constructor in inner class Feature, but I get `Could not find matching constructor for: C$Feature(java.lang.String)`, here is my code:

```
class C {
    class Feature {
        Feature(String ext) {
            this.ext = ext
        }
        String ext
    }
}

class C2 extends C {
    def m() {
        new Feature("smth")
    }
}

class RoTry {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        new C2().m()
    }
}
```

## update

my groovy version is

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-02-16 05:09:33 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     586be72bf6e3df1ee7676d1f2a3afd9157341274

Groovy:       2.3.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
```

Comment: You probably can't make a Feature without making an instance of A. Try putting this in your `m` method instead: `new C.Feature(new C(), "smth")`

Comment: I tried your code, if you remove the syntax errors it compiles...

Comment: that should be `new C.Feature("smth")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-private inner classes require a formal parameter in the constructor: see [Do default constructors for private inner classes have a formal parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896831/do-default-constructors-for-private-inner-classes-have-a-formal-parameter).

Therefore, inside method `m()` you should use `new Feature(this, 'smth')`:

```
class C {
    class Feature {
        String ext

        Feature(String ext) {
            this.ext = ext
        }

        String toString() {
            ext
        }        
    }

    def n() {
        new Feature('nnnn')
    }
}

class C2 extends C {
    def m() {
        new Feature(this, 'mmmm')
    }
}

def c = new C()
println c.n()

def c2 = new C2()
println c2.m()
```

With reflection, you can see it:

```
C.Feature.class.getDeclaredConstructors().each { constructor ->
    println constructor
}

--

public C$Feature(C,java.lang.String)
```

Comment: It's the best way what i find